# dnsmasq split-horizon DNS IPv6 and CNAME

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, dnsmasq

I maintain domain name `example.com` which has a subdomain `a.example.com`.
Public DNS server for `a.example.com` is configured with a `CNAME foo.example.com` record which in turn points to AWS.
Outside of my LAN this all works as expected.

For dual stack LAN I'm trying to setup dnsmasq such that within lan `a.example.com` resolves to local IPv4 address rather than CNAME record from public DNS.
My dnsmasq config is:

```
dhcp-range=10.10.10.1,10.10.10.254,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,10.10.0.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,10.10.0.1
dhcp-option=option:netmask,255.255.0.0

local=/lan/
domain=lan

no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=4.4.4.4

dhcp-hostsfile=/opt/services/dnsmasq/lan/etc/dhcp-hosts.txt
```

I've added following lines to /etc/hosts on the machine running dnsmasq:

```
10.10.100.100 a.example.com
2603:******** a.example.com
```

However clients on the lan when querying for `AAAA` record of `a.example.com` still get CNAME record that takes them outside of the LAN.

```
> nslookup -debug a.example.com 10.10.0.1

Server:     10.10.0.1
Address:    10.10.0.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    a.example.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  a.example.com
    internet address = 10.10.100.100
    ttl = 0
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Name:   a.example.com
Address: 10.10.100.100
------------
    QUESTIONS:
    a.example.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  foo.example.com
    canonical name = foo.example.com.
    ttl = 300
    ->  foo.example.com
    canonical name = ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
    ttl = 300
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    origin = dns-external-master.amazon.com
    mail addr = root.amazon.com
    serial = 119290
    refresh = 600
    retry = 120
    expire = 604800
    minimum = 900
    ttl = 900
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
a.example.com   canonical name = foo.example.com.
foo.example.com canonical name = ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

dnsmasq doesn't seem to care about IPv6 record in the `/etc/hosts` file and still forwards the request upstream, gets CNAME answer and returns it to the client.

Is there a way to fix that and completely suppress responses from the upstream server for `a.example.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a silly mistake on my end.

The script that I believed was restarting dnsmasq after config change didn't actually restart it, so me adding IPv6 entry to /etc/hosts was having no effect.

After dnsmasq restart AAAA record from /etc/hosts is returned as expected.

Case closed.